# Implementing functor typeclasses

Tags: haskell, types

I just started learning haskell and I have this code which won't compile:

```
data Foo a b = Foo a b deriving (Show)

instance Functor (Foo a) where
  fmap f (Foo a b) = Foo (f a) b
```

If I change the fmap implementation a bit to this, then it works:

```
  fmap f (Foo a b) = Foo a (f b)
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: You’re saying `Foo a` is a functor, so its values have to have the type `Foo a b` (they do) and `fmap` has to apply a function `b -> c` to a `Foo a b` to get a `Foo a c` (it doesn’t in the first example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we have

```
data Foo a b = Foo a b
```

and

```
instance Functor (Foo k) where
```

then for all functions you define in your typeclass, the first parameter `a` is fixed. With that single line, you tell the world that for any `k`, `Foo k` will be a functor. However, that means that your first parameter cannot be mapped over with `fmap`:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Remember, our functor will be `Foo k`. So we will end up with

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (Foo k) a -> (Foo k) b
--                  ^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^
--                    |             |
--                    +-------+-----+
--                            |
--                      f from above
```

When you've used `fmap` on the first argument, you created the following implementation of `fmap`:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (Foo a) z -> (Foo b) z
--                  ^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^
--                     |             |
--                     +-------+-----+
--                             |
--                  err, those 'f's differ
```

Which is why your first variant didn't work, but the latter did.

Comment: Thanks for giving me that 'aha!' moment